# Reduce on-call volume to zero on LineageOS 17.1

Tags: volume-control, volume, speaker, speakerphone, calls

I have purchased a pair of **headphones** which are cheap and **too loud**. Now when listening to **media**, there's ways to reduce their amplitude, and I've **used ViPER** and liked it's performance more than the built in AudioFX (which is now frozen through Lucky Patcher). *I should mention that I've never needed audio balancers for apps, because those sounds can go quite low as required.*

However, **ViPER does nothing to the in call volume**, the real thing I have a problem with. Maybe because *calls are not processed as "multimedia sounds" and hence are not linked to "audio processing drivers"(?)* All calls through the headphones are too loud to listen to.

Is there a way I could **route audio from calls** (and also any audio treated as call sounds, like that in Google Meet) **to multimedia(?) drivers?** I'm guessing that'd come at the cost of *laggy performance on a 2GB RAM device*. Can I toggle some other **on call volume options instead**? Maybe through code? I am a root user (obviously) and may be willing to use Terminal if it doesn't get too complex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update one and a half years later: There **is** no easy way to resolve problems like these. You mostly have to wait for another update or switch to a different custom ROM.